# Как запустить тестовый git сервер?

Tags: сервер, git, macos, terminal

Есть тестовое задание. Для его выполнения нужно сделать:

> Testing server: https://github.com/bischak/websocketpuzzle.git

```
Clone and switch to branch "server"
To start the server you need to perform "activator run"  in console 
In the browser, the server returns the required URL-to connect.
```

Все клонировали, перешёл на другую ветку, но в консоли команда:

```
activator run
```

Не работает, и показывает ошибку:

```
-bash: activator: command not found
```

Запускаю все на маке в терминале. Может есть идеи или напутствия?

Comment: `./activator run`

Comment: тогда пишет: -bash: ./activator: Permission denied

Comment: `chmod +x activator`

Comment: sudo chmod a+x ./activator

Comment: "activator run" in console In the browser <-- разве речь не о браузере?

Comment: я хз) уже все испробовал! тогда как запустить этот сервер?

Comment: @norbornen я бы не стал использовать судо для каждой команды

Comment: я бы тоже. но у него, судя по сообщению, проблемы с доступом к файлу

Comment: @norbornen для решения которых судо не нужен

Comment: @Etki, (состеродочился), согласен, тут sudo лишний

Comment: Вроде бы к iOS не имеет отношения, убрал метку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запустилось, правда до конца понять как и почему не удалось! Алгоритм бил таковой.

1. Сначала когда вводил ([Etki](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/16095/etki)): `./activator run` - была ошибка -

> -bash: ./activator: Permission denied

2. Потом товарищ [norbornen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2659/norbornen) подсказал ввести:

> sudo chmod a+x ./activator run

Но ошибка не заставила себя ждать:

> chmod: run: No such file or directory

И потом думаю дай введу еще разок

> ./activator run

И эта беда внезапно заработала! Как-то так. Всем спасибо за оперативные ответы. Пошел писать приложения.

Comment: Потому что я все правильно написал, и товарищ правильно написал. Запуск осуществляется моей командой, но до chmod прав на запуск файла не было, поэтому ОС обрубала попытки.

Comment: товарищ norbornen написал "sudo chmod a+x ./activator", а вот "run" ты сам выдумал. в итоге ты изменил права на activator, отгрёб на изменении прав несуществующего run и смог запустить скрипт.

Comment: Вам спасибо огромное!!